# Forward email to other servers if the recipient doesn't exist in alias map

Tags: email, postfix

This is the first time I am starting to write a more complex postfix as I hate setting up mail settings without knowing what to do. But right now I am required to do.

**Here the setting:**

For internal reasons I am required to have my postfix relay set up like this:

> If recipient of an email is doesn't exist in alias map but the recipient domain does, postfix will send it to real mail server.

Okay, this reads strange, but I am giving you an example.

MX record of example.com  is set to ProxyHost but the real mailserver with all accounts is reachable under external.example.com

In mysql I have setup redirect@example.com should be forwarded to my@example.net. This is working right now.

But if I am sending a mail to **whatever@example.com** where **whatever** is NOT in the local mysql forwarding table but as you can see **example.com** is, I would love to forward the mail to the real mail server. This real server information was located in the **domains table** in the **realmx column**.

This does not look very hard on me, but I am not able to handle it. Right now all mails to **whatever@example.com** are just getting rejected.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Server Fault. I've edited your post to make it more readable. If the changes conflict with your intent, please forgive me and you can always re-edit it.

Comment: Anyway, I'm still confuse with this part `MX record of example.com is set to ProxyHost `. What do you mean by `ProxyHost`?

Comment: Good morning and thanks for editing the post. It was very late last evening... The normal problem of a weekend rollout...

I would love to have this structure:

**User sends mail -> all MX are set to ProxyHost ( redirecting all mails if a target is set ) -> If no redirection target is set find out the "real MX" of the mails and send them to the MX that should catch the mails **

Comment: I can just repeat what masegaloeh said, what do you mean by *ProxyHost*? Is this a service provider? Is it a company where you have your servers? Is it a kind of mail firewall?

Comment: Ahh, now I understand the question...

ProxyHost is a postfix server in the middle running on a virtual machine. 

So you have UsersComputer -> his SMTP Server sending the mail -> my postfix server being the MX and receiving the mail -> redirecting the mail to a new mailserver on another server or to a new mailbox on another server but not storing any kind of email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a very standard and typical setup. Postfix runs on a server which is external facing and receives mail and passes it on to the server which has the mailbox:

`world -> smtp.example.com -> imap.example.com`

On your `smtp` server (which you call `ProxyHost` but I won't use this term as it's not really a proxy in the general usage of the term), you will use configurations as follow (you'll have to adjust to your exact scenario, these are general guidelines):

```
mydestination = localhost
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
relay_domains = example.com
relay_recipient_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relay_recipients
```

`/etc/postfix/relay_recipients`
 will contain the list of valid recipients.

`/etc/postfix/transport`
 will list the destination for the final destination of the mail.

Full documentation and complete explanation of each configurations above can be found in the great Postfix manual. Start with the [relay_domains](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#relay_domains) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

*Warning: not-tested query | not-tested setup.*
*Because you only gave little information about your setup, then I assume that you set the alias via `virtual_alias_maps`.*

**The first problem** is avoid getting rejected. The solution is define `relay_domains` with mysql maps

```
relay_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/relay_domains
```

with query part is

```
SELECT 1 FROM forwarding WHERE email LIKE '%%@%s' LIMIT 1;
```

**The second problem** is redirect email to the *realmx*. The solution is define `transport_maps` with mysql maps joining forwarding and domain table

```
relay_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/relay_domains
```

with query part is

```
SELECT domain.realmx FROM domain INNER JOIN forwarding ON email LIKE CONCAT ('%',domain.domain) WHERE domain.domain = '%d' LIMIT 1;
```

[The SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c9654/3)